# Minimum time to reach every node in the graph having connected components

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

consider a graph without cycles. The graph have K distinct pairs in contact with each other.if we want to sent a letter to all the persons. sending a letter takes a unit time. we want to speed up the process. So what will be the minimum time for the letter to reach every person(node of graph). we can hand over letter to anyone of the connected component amoung all the connected components

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They key point is that the graph has no cycles. Thus each component of your graph is a tree. See Wikipedia for more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)

Let us assume in the following, that your graph has only one component and `n` nodes. If your graph has multiple components, just take the largest one and set *n* to the number of nodes of this component.

The worst case is, that the delivery of a letter goes from a leaf node (at the bottom) up to the root node (at the top) and then down to another leaf node. This path has length `(n-1)`. Thus this delivery takes `(n-1)` time.

To use other words: The longest path in a tree with `n` nodes has length `n-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic programming to solve these kinds of problem statements.